# How to select element with class and ends with attribute using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a set of Yes / No radio buttons that I want to select using jQuery; however, I only want to select ones with the class "required" and ones that end with the id "yes".  How do I do this?

```
$('.required').('[id$="yes"]').on('change',function(){

        ...

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I only want to select ones with the class "required" and ones that end with the id "yes".

If you mean you want only elements with class "required" that also have an id ending in "yes" then simply combine the selectors within the same string:

```
$('.required[id$="yes"]')
```

(Note: don't leave a space or it will look for `[id$="yes"]` elements that are descendants of `.required` elements.)

Or use the [`.filter()` method](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), which in my opinion is more readable:

```
$('.required').filter('[id$="yes"]')
```

If you mean that you want elements with class "required" in addition to (other) elements that have an id ending in "yes" then combine the selectors with a comma:

```
$('.required,[id$="yes"]')
```